# Passing URL parameters to iframe to Typeform

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, typeform

I'm having trouble passing URL parameters into a embedded Iframe.

I'm not sure where to start so apologies for being vague!

I'm using a service called typeform - they allow you to pass customised data into a Url which then renders for the person viewing it. I.e https://www.tutory.typeform/wtwtrew/firstname=xxxx

They provide an embed code but I don't know how to dynamically pass the "xxxx" into the code which is embedded. The code they provide is below:

```
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">

  <!--Add the title of your typeform below-->
  <title>RSVP</title>

   <!--CSS styles that ensure your typeform takes up all the available screen space (DO NOT EDIT!)-->
  <style type="text/css">
html{
margin: 0;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
iframe{
position: absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
top:0;
border:0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="typeform-full" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="https://    
tutory.typeform.com/to/IbCGf9?firstname=xxxxx&lastname=xxxxx&organisation=xxxxx&position=xxxxx&salutation=xxxxx&contactnumber=xxxxx&email=xxxxx&embed=full"></iframe> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/share.typeform.com/embed.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be so awesome!!

Comment: do you have these data to pass on to link in the client side(php)? if so just put the variables to URL like: `firstname=<?=$firstname ?>`?